# License plate enumeration

Tags: combinatorics

In France, License plates are as following :

A Two Letter block, then a three cifer block and last a two letter block. (for example DC-359-MN)
The blocks SS and WW aren't used in the left block and WW isn't used in the right block. The cifer block starts at 001 and the letters I,O and U aren't used.

I have three questions, but the last one bothers me :

1. How many plates can be made with this system ?
2. How many are there with exactly one A and one 7 ?
3. How many are there with at least one A and one 7 ?

Can someone confirm my answer to the firs two questions one and help me for the last one ? Here is my answers :

1.
$$
\left[\binom{23}{1}\binom{23}{1}-2\right].\left[\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{1}-1\right].\left[\binom{23}{1}\binom{23}{1}-1\right]=277.977.744
$$

2. I split into A being in th right block or A being in the left block :
   $$
   \left[\binom{22}{1}\binom{22}{1}\right].\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{1}\binom{9}{1}.\left[\binom{22}{1}\binom{2}{1}-1\right]+\left[\binom{2}{1}\binom{22}{1}-2\right].\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{1}\binom{9}{1}.\left[\binom{2}{1}\binom{22}{1}\right]=10.317.780
   $$
3. For th third one, I was about to split into saying that the license plate contains exactly one A, or two, or three or four ... That looks too exhaustive, is there another simpler way to proceed ?

Comment: For the last one why not do 1 minus the probability of the compliment of the event.

Comment: You are allowing $000$ in the middle

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wrote it wrong but actually the numerical value was not counting the 000, thanks. And @MilosTasic the complement of the event would be " The plate countains less than one A and one 7, and computing the case with no A and no 7 is hard, am i wrong ?

Comment: @Atmos I don't think so, try doing what you did in question one but rather than remove the letters I,O and U, remove the letters I,O,U and A. For the numbers i leave that up to you.